# Create an abook address book from ldapsearch results

Tags: ldap, ldif

I'd liket to have an offline address book. To download the content of the online address book, I just do :

```
ldapsearch -x '(objectclass=*)' > book
```

Then, I try to convert it to abook format :

```
  abook --convert --infile book --outfile abook --informat ldif --outformat abook
```

But abook complains :

```
  cannot read file book
```

It may be because ldapsearch default output is an "extended ldif format" according to hte man. So I tried with `-LLL` but ldapsearch complains `error: Size limit exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting to specify paged output like this:

```
ldapsearch -x '(objectClass=*)' -E pr=500/noprompt > book
```

This will give back pages of 500 results with no extra interaction required so should do what you need.